# How to create public shareable link for private user resources in MERN application

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, mongoose, redux

I am creating a movie web application using MERN stack where a user can sign up and login. Users can also add the movies they like to their respective list.

Now, I want to add a feature where the user can share their created list with anyone through a shareable link just like how we give access to files on google drive without the person requiring to login.

Please give me some insights on how this can be achieved.

Model of the database I want to share.

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const FavoritesSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    user: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: "user",
    },
    imdbID: {
        type: String,
        require: true,
    },
    Poster: {
        type: String,
        require: true,
    },
    Title: {
        type: String,
        require: true,
    },
    Type: {
        type: String,
        require: true,
    },
    Year: {
        type: String,
        require: true,
    },
    date: {
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now,
    },
});

module.exports = mongoose.model("favorites", FavoritesSchema);
```

server.js

```
const express = require("express");
const dotenv = require("dotenv");
const connectDB = require("./config/db");
const path = require("path");

const cors = require("cors");
const axios = require("axios");

dotenv.config();

const app = express();

connectDB();
app.use(cors());

app.all("*", (req, res, next) => {
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "https://localhost:3000");
    next();
});

app.use(express.json({ extended: false }));

app.use("/api/users", require("./routes/users"));
app.use("/api/auth", require("./routes/auth"));
app.use("/api/mylist", require("./routes/mylist"));

app.get("/api/data/:searchValue", async (req, res) => {
    const { searchValue } = req.params;
    console.log(searchValue);
    const response = await axios.get(
        `http://www.omdbapi.com/?apikey=${process.env.REACT_APP_CLIENT_SECRET}&s=${searchValue}`
    );
    console.log(response.data);
    return res.send(response.data);
});

app.get("/api/data/:searchValue/:currentPage", async (req, res) => {
    const { searchValue, currentPage } = req.params;
    console.log(searchValue);
    const response = await axios.get(
        `http://www.omdbapi.com/?apikey=${process.env.REACT_APP_CLIENT_SECRET}&s=${searchValue}&page=${currentPage}`
    );
    console.log(response.data);
    return res.send(response.data);
});
//FOR PRODUCTION

__dirname = path.resolve();
app.use("/uploads", express.static(path.join(__dirname, "/uploads")));

if (process.env.NODE_ENV === "production") {
    app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, "frontend/build")));

    app.get("*", (req, res) =>
        res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, "frontend", "build", "index.html"))
    );
}

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000;

app.listen(
    PORT,
    console.log(`server started in ${process.env.NODE_ENV} mode on port ${PORT}`)
);
```

Users list route.
routes/mylist.js

```
const express = require("express");
const router = express.Router();

const auth = require("../middleware/auth");

const { body, validationResult } = require("express-validator");

const User = require("../models/User");

const Favorite = require("../models/Favorites");

// @route GET api/mylist
// @get a users all lists of movies
// @access Private
router.get("/", auth, async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const favorites = await Favorite.find({ user: req.user.id }).sort({
            date: -1,
        });
        res.json(favorites);
        // console.log(favorites);
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(error.message);
        res.status(500).send("Server Error");
    }
    // res.send("Get the user all lists of movies");
});

// @route POST api/mylist
// @get a users all lists of movies
// @access Private
router.post(
    "/",
    [
        auth,

        [
            body("Poster", "Poster is required").not().isEmpty(),
            body("Title", "imdbid is required").not().isEmpty(),
            body("Type", "Type is required").not().isEmpty(),
            body("Year", "Year is required").not().isEmpty(),
            body("imdbID", "imdbid is required").not().isEmpty(),
        ],
    ],
    async (req, res) => {
        const errors = validationResult(req);
        if (!errors.isEmpty()) {
            return res.status(400).json({ errors: errors.array() });
        }

        const { Poster, Title, Type, Year, imdbID } = req.body;

        try {
            const newFavorite = new Favorite({
                imdbID,
                Poster,
                Type,
                Year,
                Title,
                user: req.user.id,
            });
            const favorite = await newFavorite.save();
            console.log(newFavorite);
            res.json(favorite);
        } catch (error) {
            console.error(error.message);
            res.status(500).send("Server Error");
        }
        // res.send("Add a movie to mylist ");
    }
);

router.delete(
    "/:id",
    [auth, [body("_id", "_id is required").not().isEmpty()]],
    async (req, res) => {
        try {
            let favorite = await Favorite.findById(req.params.id);

            if (!favorite) return res.status(401).json({ msg: "Movie not found" });

            if (favorite.user.toString() !== req.user.id) {
                return res.status(401).json({ msg: "Not Authorized" });
            }

            await Favorite.findByIdAndRemove(req.params.id);

            res.json({ msg: "Movie Removed" });
            console.log("hey");
        } catch (error) {
            console.error(error.message);
            res.status(500).send("Server Error");
        }
        // res.send("Add a movie to mylist ");
    }
);

module.exports = router;
```

actions/favorites.js

```
import axios from "axios";
import {
    GET_FAVORITE_SUCCESS,
    GET_FAVORITE_FAIL,
    ADD_FAVORITE_SUCCESS,
    ADD_FAVORITE_FAIL,
    DELETE_FAVORITE_SUCCESS,
    DELETE_FAVORITE_FAIL,
} from "../actions/types";

import { setAuthToken } from "../utils/setAuthToken";

export const getFavoriteMovies = () => async (dispatch) => {
    console.log("i am here in actions");
    if (localStorage.token) {
        setAuthToken(localStorage.token);
    }
    const config = {
        headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
        },
    };
    // const body = JSON.stringify({ imdbid });
    try {
        const res = await axios.get("/api/mylist", config);
        console.log(res.data);
        dispatch({
            type: GET_FAVORITE_SUCCESS,
            payload: res.data,
        });
    } catch (error) {
        dispatch({
            type: GET_FAVORITE_FAIL,
            payload: error.response,
        });
    }
};

export const createFavoriteMovies =
    ({ Title, Year, imdbID, Type, Poster }) =>
    async (dispatch) => {
        console.log("i am here in create action");
        console.log({ Title });
        if (localStorage.token) {
            setAuthToken(localStorage.token);
        }
        const config = {
            headers: {
                "Content-Type": "application/json",
            },
        };
        const body = JSON.stringify({ Title, Year, imdbID, Type, Poster });
        try {
            const res = await axios.post("/api/mylist", body, config);
            console.log(res.data);
            dispatch({
                type: ADD_FAVORITE_SUCCESS,
                payload: res.data,
            });
        } catch (error) {
            dispatch({
                type: ADD_FAVORITE_FAIL,
                payload: error.response,
            });
        }
    };

export const deleteFavoriteMovies = (id) => async (dispatch) => {
    console.log("i am here in delete action");
    console.log(id);
    if (localStorage.token) {
        setAuthToken(localStorage.token);
    }
    // const config = {
    //  headers: {
    //      "Content-Type": "application/json",
    //  },
    // };
    try {
        const res = await axios.delete(`/api/mylist/${id}`);
        console.log(res.data);
        dispatch({
            type: DELETE_FAVORITE_SUCCESS,
            payload: res.data,
        });
        console.log(res.data);
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
        dispatch({
            type: DELETE_FAVORITE_FAIL,
            payload: error.response,
        });
    }
};
```

**In this component I want to place that share link through which the user can share it to everyone from which they can see the list with signing up.**

components/src/MyList.Js

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import axios from "axios";
import { useSelector, useDispatch } from "react-redux";
import { getFavoriteMovies } from "../../actions/favorites";
import { deleteFavoriteMovies } from "../../actions/favorites";

import { setAuthToken } from "../../utils/setAuthToken";

import { MyListItems } from "./MyListItems";

import "./MyList.css";

export const MyList = () => {
    // const dispatch = useDisptach();
    const dispatch = useDispatch();
    const favoriteList = useSelector((state) => state.favorites);
    const { favorites } = favoriteList;

    useEffect(() => {
        dispatch(getFavoriteMovies());
    }, [dispatch]);

    console.log(favoriteList);
    return (
        <div className='mylist-container'>
            <h1>My List</h1>
            <button className='add-to-favorite-button'>Share your list</button>
            <div className='movies-container'>
                {" "}
                {favorites !== null &&
                    favorites.map((myList) => (
                        <MyListItems myList={myList} key={myList.id} />
                    ))}
            </div>
        </div>
    );
};
```

Image of the movie list data fetched for a user as private route.
[image]

I want to create a shareable link created by the registered user for this list to show to all other visitors who visits this link

Comment: I found the solution of this by creating an API endpoint for the user database that was **favorites** in my case without wrapping it with auth middleware and fetching the data.

The code I used for that is 
`
`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution of this by creating an API endpoint for the user database that was **favorites** in my case without wrapping it with auth middleware and fetching the data.

The code I used for that is in server.js

```
app.get("/api/share/:id", async (req, res) => {
    const { id } = req.params;
    const favorites = await Favorite.find({ user: id }).sort({
        date: -1,
    });
    res.json(favorites);

});
```

In this way I was able to get the my list data from the database depending upon the user id in the query parameter.
I used the relation of the user in the schema of favorites I had.

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const FavoritesSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    user: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: "user",
    },
    imdbID: {
        type: String,
        require: true,
    },
    Poster: {
        type: String,
        require: true,
    },
    Title: {
        type: String,
        require: true,
    },
    Type: {
        type: String,
        require: true,
    },
    Year: {
        type: String,
        require: true,
    },
    date: {
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now,
    },
});

module.exports = mongoose.model("favorites", FavoritesSchema);
```

I was able to solve it like this.
Thank you for all the help.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add String type array to your mongoose scheme.When user add films to own list these films links will push your array.after that you simply can share it anywere if you want.
add to your mongoose scheme
list: [String]

Comment: Thank you for the help, but i am not totally sure how to do that and what you are meaning. Can you please provide some code for clear understanding.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I will do it.

Generate a unique id that you will use to identify the favorite list (I will use the UUID package https://www.npmjs.com/package/uuid)

Say I generated a unique id, I need to associate it to a favorite list in the DB.

I will make use of the node-cache library (https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-cache).

For example, the id of my favorite list is **62477be0e5372c02a82b2983**

```
const NodeCache = require( "node-cache" );
const { v4: uuidv4 } = require('uuid');

const favoriteCache = new NodeCache();

const favoriteListId = "62477be0e5372c02a82b2983";
const shareableCode = uuidv4(); // ⇨ '1b9d6bcd-bbfd-4b2d-9b5d-ab8dfbbd4bed'

favoriteCache.set(shareableCode,favoriteListId);
```

In the code above, I have saved in the cache a unique id and set its value to the id of the favorite list.

Now I want to retrieve the list using the code.

```
router.get("/shared/:code", auth, async (req, res) => {
    const {code} = req.params;
    const listId = favoriteCache.get(code);
    if (!listId) return res.status(400).send('invalid share code');
    const list = await Favorite.find({_id: listId});
    res.json(list);
})
```

If you restart your app the codes will be removed from the cache, you can make use of the db to save the code to make them persistent. But If you are looking to have the sharing codes last for a few hours, then this is one of the ways you can do it. You can also set a third parameter to the set function of the cache to assign an expiration time.

Comment: I tried to understand what your approach is. But I am having some doubts like 

`router.get("/shared/:code", auth, async (req, res) `
what does the param **:code** represents and from where it is received ? And also, I don't have the whole list id, I have each object id's and I want to fetch the users data through the shared link through the user id or object. I hope this makes sense. How can i do that?